# How to make an animation clip on Unity to loop

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the Unity Mecanim, and I have two animation clips:

[image]

The problem is that when the animation of a clip finish it doesnt start again from the beggining, it doesnt loop, and I cannot find any option to make it loop.

[image]

Any help, where to look for the loop options?

**EDIT:**

I find the options according to the answers here but there are not editable, is it because I download this from Asset Store?

[image]

Comment: I have not used mecanim yet, but I have made animations (created in Unity), they are saved as .anim files (I think). If you have them, click on it and there is an option where you can specify if you want the animation to loop. As I said, I don't know if with mecanim there's another way, but this is how I made for the music

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 15):

Its probably too late to help you with this, but just incase anyone else has this issue, your looping options are greyed out because your animation from the asset store is read-only, select your animation in the project window, and press Ctrl+D to duplicate it, and you should be able to now set the looping options on the new animation as the other answerers have described.

Answer (score 6):

Click on your Run_Impulse animation file and there is an option:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-AnimationClip.html

Loop Pose option should be cheked for make it loop

Here, there is more information about making loop an animation clip:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoopingAnimationClips.html

EDIT: I add an image. You have to select your imported FBX (not the animation file inside) and check the Loop Time.

[image: Select the Animations tab from your IMPORTED fbx]

Comment: I find the options according to the answers here but there are not editable, is it because I download this from Asset Store?

Comment: hmm maybe. Then you importen the animation, right? Have a look at this link : "http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9153/why-cant-i-edit-animation-curves-imported-from-may.html" . The animation might be "read-only" if you imported the fbx. In the second commend, that guy says that "You can use an editor script that copies over the curves from the original imported Animation Clip into the duplicated Animation Clip."

Comment: Try selecting the FBX imported (when you import the FBX, inside there is the animation with the "play icon"). So, instead of selecting this file, you have to select the imported fbx, and goto Animation and check Loop Time

Comment: You say "Loop Pose option should be cheked for make it loop". This is not 100% correct. "Loop Pose" makes it so that the character in the last frame is in the same position (translation) as in the first frame. So if your character moves forward in the animation, "Loop Pose" will make him walk "in-place".

Comment: Remember to click apply.

Answer (score 3):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/204331/animation-loop.html

> Go to the animation and set it as looping .In the Animation window look at the bottom for something that should say 'Default' - it's a drop-down menu with looping options (Loop starts the animation over, PingPong plays it back and forth, Clamp Forever freezes the animation at the state of the last frame etc.)

Comment: I find the options according to the answers here but there are not editable, is it because I download this from Asset Store?

Comment: I've had a quick look and from what I can see you need to select the animation itself instead of the clip and then the animation options are available.