# Setting animation loop end point in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want to set arbitrary loop points within an animation.
So for example, if my animation is 10seconds long I might want to loop from 8 to 9 seconds in.
When I set a loop, I see a "Cycle offset", which allows me to set where the loop starts but not where it ends.

I've also searched the docs and found this:[article](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoopingAnimationClips.html) but I cant seem to find the window it refers to.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809514/how-to-make-an-animation-clip-on-unity-to-loop

Comment: Hey, that post seems to deal with setting it to loop, where are I am asking how to set the end loop point.

Comment: Unity provides a window in the Inspector to handle the loop. There you can set the start and the end using a slider. If your problem is to find that window, here it is: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimationClip.html 

You have to use clip-specific import Animation Clips. It works for FBX data, I don't know if it works for animation created inside Unity

Comment: Thanks @Vinserello. What was throwing me was the menu only appears when you click the model, not when you click the animation! (Unity is so badly designed) Also then menu doesn't appear until you click "import animation.
However this still doesn't quite do what I need.
I need the animation to play from the start and then just loop around at the end, instead of just looping from the in to the out points.
So for example, if the animation was 10 secs long, I want to play from 0 to 8 and then loop from 8 to 10.
Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is not possible to set an end point. I would implement a script attached to the animated gameobject. If you want, we can try this solution, but maybe it won't even work

Comment: Seems so basic. I'm really beginning to hate unity. It's unintuitive/buggy and badly designed. Like why would you set animation variables on the Geometry file, not the animation? Makes no sense.

Comment: No, you can create your own Animation and manage the loop via script. The script will check the current time of the Animation. If it is greater than the end point, the animation returns to the starting point of the loop. The script handles only Animation's time, not Geometry.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works. You can set your own loop points but every time you call Play(), it calls the OnStateEnter, even though you're already in that state:

```
    OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) 
    {
        if (stateInfo.normalizedTime >= 0.92f)
                animator.Play("MYSTATE", 0, 0.71f);
    }
```